# Log user back in with remember me with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have it setup so that onced logged in, the remember me is set to true with `Auth::attempt([$u, $p], true)`;

But the session expires after 2 hours of no activity. So the user becomes logged out.

The documenation was very clear, how does the remember me work if the user is logged out after 2 hours? Am I supposed to check if the remember me cookie exists and log the user in?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By default laravel session life time is set to 120 min you can cofigure it from  config/session.php - **lifetime**.

If the user checked remeber me for an application, Laravel will queue a permanent cookie that contains the encrypted copy of the user identifier. Laravel will then decrypt this later to retrieve the users.

Answer (score 1):

If your users table has a `remember_token` column and you are using a code like the following (as you do) the user gets remembered

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)) {
    // The user is being remembered...
}
```

This is not dependent on the session because it sets a cookie like the following:

```
Name:   remember_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989a
Value   :eyJpdiI6IkRpTE9zU3ZTZElQMzJrVWFkUUR3N2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoieGs4T3JkN3c3UmdaMzFOTkhiWmRnWXNPN0x2S09cL0VJYmg1SlFRSFVnYWo2Rk04dlBoOFpEa256RlwvTFRNczhSQytPS3VJc3QyaUU4Und4QUNmdk1xZFQ2UWNFUkN4VzZPWCtGTEl0MUxwUT0iLCJtYWMiOiIwMDQ5NjgzNzUxZTc3MzUxMzcxNzQ1ZjIxYzgyOTY5MzBkZjRiZmYzYTNiNGFiODc4ZGQ1YzczNzhkMjUxMGUyIn0%3D
Host    : www.example.com
Path    /
Expires Sun, 19 Sep 2021 11:48:54 GMT
Secure  No
HttpOnly    Yes
```

This means the user is logged in for 5 years from now.

Comment: Yes, but the remember me isn't working as attended. I have to extend the session_lifetime in order to make the user stay logged in longer. After the '120' default time without activity, the user is logged out, even though the remember me is set true.

Comment: Are you sure he is logged out? What will definately happen is, that your csrf token expires, so if you are sending a form you will receive, the token mismatch exception. However browsing (normal get requests) should work. You can check your cookies. Is there a remember cookie set in your browser?